# How to access observable object values in component class in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am sending an object having two values 1- array 2- simple variable
This object is receiving in another component using observable and from there I am accessing object values directly into the html template file

Here is the code

Homecomponent

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    itemscount:Number = 0;
    cart = [];
    cartobj = {};
    constructor(private _data: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.itemscount = this.cart.length;
        this._data.cast.subscribe(res => this.cartobj = res);
        this._data.changeCart(this.cartobj);

    }

    additem(itemText){
        this.cart.push(itemText);
        this.itemscount = this.cart.length;
        this.cartobj = {cart_items:this.cart,items_count:this.itemscount}
        this._data.changeCart(this.cartobj);
    }
}
```

Header component

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    cartobj: any;
    cart = [];
    constructor(private _data: DataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._data.cast.subscribe(res =>  this.cartobj = res);
        //this.cart = this.cartobj.cart_items;
    }

}
```

header component html template

```
<li *ngFor="let items of cartobj.cart_items">
    {{ items }}
</li>

{{cartobj.items_count}}
```

Dataservice code

```
export class DataService {

    private cartobj = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
    cast = this.cartobj.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    changeCart(item_param) {
        this.cartobj.next(item_param);
        console.log(this.cartobj);
    }

}
```

Currently I am accessing the object directly in header html template. I just want to access the object in the header component file first and then in the html template.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry but this your last sentence is not clear enough: which object are your talking about? I suppose by "header component file" you mean the component controller. What do you mean by accessing from here "first"?

Comment: do you mean you want to make work this line which you commented 
 `//this.cart = this.cartobj.cart_items;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you can't do that way, you have to put this line of code in the subscribe itself, because it's asyc and your commented line will run simultaneously

Replace this code

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._data.cast.subscribe(res => this.cartobj = res);
    //this.cart = this.cartobj.cart_items;
}
```

With

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._data.cast.subscribe(res => {
            this.cartobj = res
            this.cart = this.cartobj.cart_items;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Easy and efficient answer.

Comment: This answer helped me to access the property of Object of type :any.

Comment: ERROR: `@deprecated — Use an observer instead of a complete callback`

Answer (score 6):

When you want to consume an observable in your template then usually you need the `async` pipe, so probably you mean

`<li *ngFor="let items of (cartobj | async).cart_items">
    {{ items }}
</li>`

Comment: It is clearly written I want to access the values in "component class". I had already access it in template.

Answer (score 0):

Also with Promise

```
const cast = await this._data.cast.toPromise();
```